# adjacency matrix of random geometric graphs

Tags: graph-theory, matrix-analysis, random-graphs, matrix-theory, adjacency-matrices

Consider a graph with N nodes. All nodes are distributed as a Poisson point process with density of λ in a L*L area. There is an edge between two nodes if and only if the distance between them is less than or equal to R. What is the adjacency matrix of this graph? What is the distribution of 0,1 in this adjacency matrix?

Comment: The correct terminology is "adjacency matrix"

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to read up on "What is a random geometric graph?" before posing further similar questions on this site.  There are many references; for mathematics I would suggest:

> Matthew Penrose *Random Geometric Graphs* Oxford University Press (2003)
>
> Mark Walters *Random Geometric Graphs* in *Surveys in Combinatorics* London Mathematical Society (2011).

For applications in wireless networks:

> Guoqiang Mao and Brian D. O. Anderson, IEEE/ACM Trans. Network. **20** 408-421 (2012).
>
> Justin P. Coon, Carl P. Dettmann and Orestis Georgiou, J. Stat. Phys. **147** 758-778 (2012).